# OpenVPN installed using Amazon AMI, route only some traffic through the VPN

Tags: vpn, routing, openvpn, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

Used this AMI ami-b7418dd7

followed this guide: https://docs.openvpn.net/how-to-tutorialsguides/virtual-platforms/amazon-ec2-appliance-ami-quick-start-guide/

Now, when a user connects to the VPN I want all of their normal internet traffic to go through the public internet, but when they are trying to access one of our internal systems I want that traffic to go through the VPN.

How?

I've seen a lot of other answers, and I've found very few of them helpful. On this official AMI from openvpn, I can't find any `server.conf` or `client.conf` files that so many answers seem to point toward.

Any help appreciated, this is the single stupidest task to be given as a software engineer, not an IT / systems-administrator.

Answer (score 0):

This is called Split-Tunneling. To activate it you need to:

1. Open your OpenVPN GUI: https://Your_OpenVPN_IP/admin
2. Click on "VPN Settings" or write https://Your_OpenVPN_IP/admin/vpn_settings on your browser
3. Select "Yes"

[image: Selcect Yes]

4. Save Settings and Update Running Server.

Comment: Yes thanks, but then how and where do I actually define the rules for the split-tunneling?

Comment: Selecting "No" above means you configured split-tunneling.